# Copy constructor problem

Tags: c++, constructor, copy-constructor

I tried to use copy constructor using statement:

```
X y = X();
```

But copy constructor is not being called. I am using g++ 4.1.0. I set both X(const X&) and X(x&) constructor in the class.

Is this supposed to work or I am doing some very basic problem in the code?

My code for the class is

```
class A
{
 public:
  int i;

  A(int ii)
  {
   i = ii;
  }

  A(const A&)
  {
   i = 5;
  }

  A(A&)
  {
   i = -1;
  }

  A()
  {
   i = 5000;
  }
};
```

When I use it using 
`A a = A();` or   `A a = A(100);`, it does not work but when i use it `A a(b);` or `A a = b;` it works fine.

What is the point I am missing? I saw that according to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_constructor) , it should work but it's not working in my case :(.

Thanks in advance for all your answers and comments.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The compiler is permitted to elide the call to the copy constructor in certain situations.  Initializing an object from a temporary is one of them.  In this case, the temporary is simply constructed in-place instead of constructing a temporary and then copying it into the named object.

You can call the copy constructor by constructing a named object then making a copy of that:

```
X x;
X y = x;
```

Comment: I thought the compiler is __always__ allowed to elide copying?

Comment: @sbi:  There are only two times that copy elision may take place:  (1) when a named object is initialized with a temporary object, and (2) when an object is returned from a function (these two are listed in §12.8/15).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation. Now I understand the exact reason for the behavior. I think I should read C++ standards before shooting questions on stackoverflow but reading standards is not fun but asking questions is :).

Comment: @Atul:  I wouldn't read the standard.  It's long, boring, and extraordinarily difficult to read and comprehend.  A good C++ book would cover this sort of thing, though.

Comment: Thanks. I thought you have been reading standards looking at the you knowledge :) but I also agree a good C++ should cover these sort of things.

Answer (score 1):

```
X y = X();
```

calls the default constructor. The copy constructor is the one that takes a reference to an instance you want copied.

The point of a *copy constructor* is to take another object of the *same* type, and make a copy of it. Everything else is not a copy constructor.

Comment: ie declared as X(X& x) or X( const X& x) and called by X y = X( z );

Comment: Actually X() will default construct a temporary object, but y= should call the copy constructor, since it's declared and assigned at the same time.

Comment: Having seen the top answer I realise that my answer completely misses the point. Should I delete it? :)

Comment: The comment I made to @Dunya applies here as well.

Answer (score 0):

The copy constructor is called by the statements `X x(y);` or `X x = y;`.

When you call `X x = X();`, the default constructor is called.

When you call `X x = X(100);`, a constructor with one parameter is called. These are not copy constructors.

Comment: Officially, `X x = X();` default constructs a temporary, then copy constructs `x` from the temporary (but the copy can elided even if the copy ctor has side effects -- and most compilers do this, so you won't normally see it).

Answer (score -1):

Copy constructors are called when you initialize an object with an another object:). In your first example it is totally natural that the copy ctors are not called, only constructors with the suitable parameter lists will be called.

Comment: Ideally, Copy Constructor should be called whenever a new object is being created(copied) from existing object and suitable copy constructor arguments are present in the class file.